# Selecting multiple ListView items with Dynamic ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an Android chat application . In my Chat Activity i have used pagination concept, means four messages will be shown to the user , just like Whats App , It shows option of `Load More` if you have more than hundred messages. For testing purpose i have used a limit of four message . Here is the snapshot.

[image]

If i click `Load More Chat` It shows me previous four messages . Here is other snapshot. `Load More Chat` is the header View set for listView .

[image]

Now suppose from the first screen shot i select last two list items , which are placed at third and fourth position of listView . like this

[image]

And now i click on `Load More Chat` option , then it automatically selects listItems which are now placed at third and fourth position , because ArrayAdapter has been updated . Here is the picture for this. Means it does not keep the item selected i chose earlier ,  so is the bug in my app.

[image]

Now i am very confused how should i resolve the problem . I have tried from my side , but in vain  .

Here is my code for listview .

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
```

Overriden methods for MultichoiceListener Are as follows .

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode arg0,
        MenuItem arg1) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_activity_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode arg0) {

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode arg0, Menu arg1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(android.view.ActionMode mode,
        int position, long id, boolean selected) {
    final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
    mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
}
```

getView method in ArrayAdapter is as follows .

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListView lv =  (ListView) parent;
    int headerCount = lv.getHeaderViewsCount();
    Log.d("d", "header count "+headerCount);
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage, parent, false);
    }
    containerLayout = (LinearLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.containerLayout);
    messageContainer = (LinearLayout)  row.findViewById(R.id.messageContainer);
    ChatMessage chatMessageObj = getItem(position);
    chatText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.singleMessage);
    timeOfChat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeOfMessage);
    chatText.setText(chatMessageObj.message);
    timeOfChat.setText(chatMessageObj.timeOfChat);
    row.setId((int) chatMessageObj.messageID);
    messageContainer.setBackgroundResource(chatMessageObj.left ? R.drawable.bubble_a : R.drawable.bubble_b);
    containerLayout.setGravity(chatMessageObj.left ? Gravity.LEFT : Gravity.RIGHT);
    return row;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated . Plz help .
Thanks!

Comment: i understand your problem, when you update adapter then the selected items are not showing(with selected) because adapter is refreshed na...is this right?

Comment: @gvsharma . yes exactly . Selected items are not being shown selected because adapter has been refreshed .

Comment: Simple thing is that, For selected messages take a boolean and make it true when selected and viceversa. Inside getView() of adapter change the background of selected messages based on this boolean flag.
Make sure you should also handle the selected items count.

my suggestion is take thios boolean in your ChatMessage class and get the boolean flag dynamically for each chatmessage object.